# Replace url query string with str_replace

Tags: php

I have some url like the following urls:

> https://example.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?**q=1280wq**
>
> https://example.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?**q=5080wq**
>
> https://example.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?**q=860**
>
> https://example.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?**q=86058**

Now I want to replace`q` value with a constant value like 589, how can I do it with `str_replace` in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$content = "https://mysite.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?q=1280wq"; 

$content = preg_replace("q=\w+", "", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://mysite.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?q=1280wq';

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query);

echo $q;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by str_replace like this:

```
<?php
$myString = 'https://example.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs?q=1280wq';
$myNewString = str_replace('?q=', '/589/', $myString); //this line replaces the '?q=' with '/589/'
echo $myNewString; //OUTPUT: https://example.com/xyz/jjJAjsjahjsjhUAUiOAkskpAs/589/1280wq
?>
```